# Making a deep copy of a LinkedList in java

Tags: java, recursion, deep-copy

I have a Linked List and I'm trying to create a copy of another Linked List and this copy is a deep copy because the element type is char. Due to the complexity of linked lists, I've tried not to use the add method. My code is shown below. Also I want to recursively add all the elements from some list to my original list but the problem with my implementation is that it only adds the first element in the list and not all of it. Why is this so?

```
public class CharLinkedList {

    private static class Node {
        private char info;
        private Node next;


        public Node(char d) {
            this.data = d;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    private int size;
    private Node head;


    public CharLinkedList() {
        this.size = 0;
        this.head = null;
    }


    public CharLinkedList(CharLinkedList some) {
        this.size = some.size;
        Node node = some.head;
        this.head = new Node(other.head.info);
        if(node.next != null)
        {
            this.head.next = new Node(node.next.info);
            node = node.next;
            this.head.next.next = new Node(node.next.info);
        }
    }

    public void addAll(CharLinkedList some) {
        if(some == null){
            return;
        }
        if (this.size == 0) {
            Node someNode = new Node(some.get(0));
            this.head = someNode;
        }
        else {
            CharLinkedList.addAll(some, this.head.next);
        }
        this.size++;
    }

    private static void addAll(CharLinkedList some, Node node) {
        if(node.next == null)
        {
            Node someNode = new Node(some.get(0));
            node.next = someNode;
        }
        else {
            CharLinkedList.addAll(some, node.next);
        }

    }



public static void main(String[] args) {
    CharLinkedList l = new CharLinkedList();
    l.add('z');
    l.add('o');
    l.add('m');

    CharLinkedList some = new CharLinkedList(l);
    some.add('b');
    some.add('i');
    some.add('e');
    System.out.println(l);
    System.out.println(some);
    // now i change the state of l and append all of some
    l.set(1,  'p');
    l.addAll(some);
    System.out.println(l);
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `LinkedList` which comes with the JCF?

Comment: So... did you ever get this to work? It would be courteous of you to accept an answer.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like an academic exercise to me (otherwise I would expect you to be using a `LinkedList<Character>` from the *[Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html)*), so I'm not going to post a completed method for you. Instead I'll try and steer you towards you creating a working deep copy implementation for yourself.

First off - I wouldn't use recursion to copy your list. If you do, you're likely to run into a `StackOverflowError` as your list gets larger and larger (admittedly, it won't be a problem for a three-element list). Secondly, rather than having a constructor that returns a deep copy of the `CharLinkedList` that you give it, I would instead override `Object`'s `clone()` method (that's what it's for after all).

**How would you copy each element into your cloned list?**

Well, you already know how large your list is, you're storing that in in your `size` attribute. You can use this value as the upper bound of a `for` loop, in which you would copy each list element in sequence.

Because your `CharLinkedList` class only maintains a reference to your *head* element, you would need to maintain a reference to the *current* `Node` outside of your loop, otherwise you'd lose your reference to the next element after each iteration.

In essence, you want something like this pseudo-code:

```
CharLinkedList newList = new CharLinkedList();
Node currentNode = head;

// There are plenty of other ways to do this, you could also use a while loop 
// checking that next is not null.
for (each element up until size) {
    // You may need to implement getData()
    Node newNode = new Node(currentNode.getData()); 
    newList.add(newNode);
    // You may need to implement getNextNode()
    currentNode = currentNode.getNextNode();
}
```

Once you're done, `return newList`, and don't forget to document that your `clone()` method returns a *deep clone* instead of a *shallow clone*. Why? **Because it's a good habit to get into.**

Finally, don't forget to take a look at the *[Java Collections Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/overview.html)*, which already contains an implementation of `LinkedList` that you can read through the source code for.

Comment: Good answer, @JonK. The only thing I would modify is that the constructor doesn't `return newList` and the `addAll` methods are void, so there's nowhere to return them.

Comment: @AlejandroLucena Thank you, although the rest of your comment has me a tad confused (I had very little sleep last night so I might just not be thinking straight!). I'm not suggesting this should be added to the constructor, quite the opposite, this *shouldn't* be in the constructor, it should be an override of `clone()`. The code above is only pseudo-code, I intentionally didn't want to give a working implementation as it would defeat the purpose of the academic exercise.

Comment: That's the point I missed -- I had missed where you said the override for `clone()`. So yes, that would be a great override for `clone()`. I have also suggested an answer below, but I didn't mention anything about the use of `clone`, +1 to you

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor for `CharLinkedList` that accepts another `CharLinkedList`, you are only using an `if` statement to check if the other linked list has another element, and if it does, it will add it as `this.head.next` . However, if there are multiple elements, you would need to make that `if` statement into a `while` and use the temp variable `node` as an "iterator" of sorts.

Something like this should do:

```
    Node node = some.head;
    this.head = new Node(some.head.info);
    Node adder = this.head; // keep track of the  adding nodes
    node = node.next; // advance the pointer to the next node
    while(node.next != null) // keep adding to the linked list while there are things to add
    {
        adder.next = new Node(node.info);
        node = node.next; // advance the pointer to the next node
    }
```

That code will traverse the `some` linked list and make a copy of each of its elements into the linked list currently being constructed.

There are several flaws in your `addAll` scheme. The most clear way to add all the elements would be to implement a solution similar to what I've wrote above, modifying where to start adding,etc. However, addressing your current style, the `addAll` that only takes a CharLinkedList is good, and correctly calls the recursive `addAll` with the additional parameters, however in that other `addAll` you are checking

```
   if(node.next == null)
```

Even though you are passing it `node.next` from the previous functionm, which is expected to be `null` anyways. Also, you cannot be so sure to always add the 0th element, since this could be a deep recursive call several links into the chain. To continue with this implementation, you can add an additional `int` parameter keeping track of where you are in the list, or an additonal `Node` parameter specifying what to add next -- the choice/stye is yours.

Hope this helps