# JAVA Immutablilty, Copying a Linked List

Tags: java, linked-list, immutability

I am tasked with creating a Linked List class in Java that MUST be immutable. This has been accomplished exactly the same as on here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/linked-list-set-1-introduction/

Among other methods, I need an *addToList* method that adds a value or multiple values to the tail of the Linked List. Since the Linked List is immutable, adding to it should create a copy of the Linked List (i.e. a new LinkedList object with the same contents) and only add the desired values to the newly created copy.

The copy function is where I need help. Below is the *copyList* function, partially completed. I am traversing each Node in the LinkedList and printing out the *data* successfully. Now I need to assign that data to the corresponding element in the *clonedList* (the new copy). Please see the image below.

```java
public LinkedList<T> copyList(LinkedList<T> toCopy) {
    Node n = toCopy.head;
    LinkedList clonedList = new LinkedList<T>();

    while(n != null) {
        System.out.println("Copying: " + n.data);
        /*code here(?) to assign elements to clonedList,
        but how?
         */
        n = n.next;

    }

    return clonedList;


}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what situations is the CopyOnWriteArrayList suitable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17853112/in-what-situations-is-the-copyonwritearraylist-suitable)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a deep copy of a LinkedList in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751588/making-a-deep-copy-of-a-linkedlist-in-java)

Comment: Please provide the code you need help with and state more precisely what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much for Java, but can't you just do

```
clonedList.add(n.data)
```

in your while loop to create a deep copy?

Comment: I cannot because (as far as I know), ".add" works on Arrayists, sets etc. This LinkedList is a class of its own, so Java doesn't know what it means when I write clonedList.add(...

Comment: Per my googling, I think you're mistaken. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-linkedlist-add-method-in-java/

Comment: @NegativeFriction I think the point is he has his own implementation without an `add` method.

Comment: I am working with a class I created called "LinkedList", I did not import it from java.util.LinkedList. That's why I can't use .add

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need a deep copy, you should just be able to set the `head` of the cloned list to that of the original, e.g.:

```java
LinkedList<T> clonedList = new LinkedList<>();
clonedList.head = toCopy.head;
```

Otherwise, construct a new Node on each loop iteration and add it to the cloned list. It sounds to me like you have your own `LinkedList` implementation without an `add` method, so either write one or replace the method call in the example.

```java
Node<T> n = toCopy.head;
LinkedList<T> clonedList = new LinkedList<>();

while(n != null) {
    Node<T> nClone = new Node<>(toCopy.data);
    clonedList.add(nClone);
    n = n.next;
}
```

Also, this method should probably either be a constructor or a static method. It doesn't make sense to require an instance for a method that doesn't modify the list's state.